# Effect of GPIO Input impedance

Tags: microcontroller, voltage-divider, gpio

[image]

I want to sense whether 14V Power input is on or not and send it to the GPIO Pin of my micro controller.The micro controller accepts any voltage greater than 2V as Logic High.Based on that ,I designed my below circuit without considering the GPIO input impedance as I could not find the information on the datasheet.Do i really to need to consider the input impedance in my case?

Added:
Here is the link for the datasheet.
http://cache.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/LPC2131_32_34_36_38.pdf?pspll=1

Comment: That looks good. You could add a link to the datasheet for your micro.

Comment: The largest component of input impedance (for a CMOS device, within range, without a pulling resistor activated) will typically be *capacitance* but assuming your signal has a low rate of change that will probably not be an issue apart from meaning the input may sit in the high-power-consumption intermediate state slightly longer.  And of course the internal capacitance is nothing compared to your 100 nF external cap.

Comment: It looks like you can expect a few microamps of reverse leakage current from each of your diodes, though those may somewhat balance out.  But it is something to consider, in keeping your divider in the hundred kilo ohm range rather than the mega ohm one.

Comment: @ChrisStratton:I don't understand what do you mean here "meaning the input may sit in the high-power-consumption intermediate state slightly longer".Could you please explin in little bit detail

Comment: Many CMOS input structures consume excess power (from their supply) when presented with an input that is in the "invalid" range between threshold voltages, as both the upper and lower FETs are partially on.  You generally want to transition that region quickly, and not sit there.

Answer (score 1):

The leakage currents of CMOS inputs are extremely small; typically (see your datasheet), the resulting input impedance (R<sub>input</sub> = V<sub>CC</sub> / I<sub>leak</sub>) is in the order of 50 MΩ.

In practice, you can assume that it is approximately infinite, and that you do not need to consider it.

Comment: . . .  also, ,  if the GPIO doesn't have any active pull up or pull down resistors enabled (internal to the micro).

Comment: @Marla "What is the impedance of that resistor?" would be a different kind of question ...

Comment: @CL: The leakage current is approximately 3uA without pullup.In that case,my input impedance would be 3.3/3uA = 1MΩ. Incase of using internal pull up,I need to calculate the internal pull up in parallel with 100kΩ right.Is my understanding correct?

Comment: A pullup would behave just like any other resistor.